# bash command line editing (Emacs shortcuts)

Tags: bash, command-line, emacs

When writing a command on the bash command line, I can use <kbd>CTRL+w</kbd> to delete a word backwards, or <kbd>ALT+d</kbd> to delete word forwards.

The problem is, that these two shortcuts are not exactly complementary: <kbd>CTRL+w</kbd> deletes everything up to a space, whereas <kbd>ALT+d</kbd> deletes only up to any non-alphabetic character (i.e. stops at `/`)

Is there a shortcut that acts as <kbd>ALT+d</kbd>, but backwards?

So that when I am at the end of `/etc/hostname`  and press shortcut, I end up with `/etc/`.

Comment: `Atl-Backspace`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bind -p` gives you the current bindings. You'll find that <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> is bound to `unix-word-rubout` and <kbd>Alt+D</kbd> to `kill-word`:

```
"\C-w": unix-word-rubout
"\ed": kill-word
```

If you do a `bind -p | grep kill-word`, you'll find:

```
"\e\C-h": backward-kill-word
"\e\C-?": backward-kill-word
```

Some terminals send `^H` upon <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and some other `^?` which is why there are two bindings. That makes it that <kbd>Alt+Backspace</kbd> should be what kills a word backward at least on those terminals where <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> sends the `ESC` character followed by `X`.

There are some terminals however that send `X` with the 8th bit set (0xD8) upon <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> (though they are becoming rarer and rarer, as that doesn't make much sense this new UTF-8 world). In those, you'll have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, or you can set `convert-meta` to `on` in the readline configuration (for instance with `bind 'set convert-meta on'`), but then you won't be able to input non-ascii characters.

Comment: `bind -p` indeed prints current bindings (several hundred lines, actually). Are these the default bindings (i.e. hardcoded) or are they defined somewhere? On my Debian Wheezy, the `/etc/inputrc` file contains only few lines. Where do they come from, if not from `/etc/inputrc` ?

Comment: @MartinVegter, yes, they are the default bindings and documented. See `info --index-search=backward-kill-word bashref`